# Fill NaN with corresponding row value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
      Region                   Date         Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered   Latitude    Longitude
0     Mainland China Anhui     2020-01-22   1.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
1     Mainland China Beijing   2020-01-22   14.0        0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
2     Mainland China Chongqing 2020-01-22   6.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
3     Mainland China Fujian    2020-01-22   1.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
4     Mainland China Gansu     2020-01-22   0.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
2825  Mainland China Anhui     2020-03-01   990.0       6.0     873.0       31.8257     117.2264
567   Mainland China Anhui     2020-02-05   1.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
2951  Mainland China Anhui     2020-03-02   990.0       6.0     917.0       31.8257     117.2264
4273  Mainland China Fujian    2020-03-07   296.0       1.0     295.0       26.0789     117.9874
4541  Mainland China Fujian    2020-03-07   296.0       1.0     295.0       26.0789     117.9874
```

I want to fill the NaN values in the Latitude and Longtitude with the corresponding value based on the region.

I tried:

```
df = df.groupby(['Region']).ffill()
df
```

But that only got me this:

```
        Date        Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered   Latitude    Longitude
0       2020-01-22  1.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
1       2020-01-22  14.0        0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
2       2020-01-22  6.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
3       2020-01-22  1.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
4       2020-01-22  0.0         0.0     0.0         NaN         NaN
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use the fact that `max` ignores NaN values, so this should be enough:

```
df.loc[:,['Latitude', 'Longitude']] = df.groupby('Region')[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].transform('max')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use back and forward fill method on grouped elements.

```
df['Latitude'] = df.groupby('Region')['Latitude'].fillna(method='backfill').fillna(method='pad')
df['Longitude'] = df.groupby('Region')['Longitude'].fillna(method='backfill').fillna(method='pad')
```